.NET MAUI on Android has stopped upload web services
In the latest version of Visual Studio (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.11.5), .NET MAUI seems to be stripping away important code or stopping important code from functioning properly in RELEASE versions of the app.
Overview:
I have an app that has been developed using .NET MAUI but lately, when using my app to complete certain tasks that require uploads, it seems to have stripped away/blocked code that is needed to upload data to the server.
This was working perfectly before, but lately we have noticed that the release version of the app is now not functional, but in debug, everything works just fine.
Here is the contents of my project file.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android</TargetFrameworks>

        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>Skillweb.Maui</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Title>SmartTask Engage</Title>
        <PackageIcon>icon.png</PackageIcon>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <MauiVersion>8.0.3</MauiVersion>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>SmartTask Engage</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>uk.co.skillweb.engage</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>73A90E3A-4FB0-46D1-BA66-89FFBAC1502C</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>2.2024.1030</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>2084</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">29.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>

        <IncrementVersionOnBuild>2.yyyy.MM.MMdd</IncrementVersionOnBuild>
        <AssemblyVersion>2.2024.1108.2113</AssemblyVersion>
        <FileVersion>2.2024.1108.2113</FileVersion>

        <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>.sonarlint\skillweb.maui_skillweb.maui_ayfmhccthtlehxqfuhtfcsharp.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>

        <PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!--<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
        <AndroidEnableMultiDex>False</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
        <EnableLLVM>True</EnableLLVM>
        <JavaMaximumHeapSize>2G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
        <AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>
        <AndroidUseAapt2>True</AndroidUseAapt2>
        <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
        <AndroidEnableMultiDex>True</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
        <EnableLLVM>True</EnableLLVM>
        <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
        <JavaMaximumHeapSize>2G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
        <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
    </PropertyGroup>-->

    <!--<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>2.2024.1108</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>2101</ApplicationVersion>
        <AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>
        <ApplicationTitle>SmartTask Engage</ApplicationTitle>
        <ApplicationId>uk.co.skillweb.engage</ApplicationId>
        <JavaMaximumHeapSize>2G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
        <Optimize>False</Optimize>
        <AndroidUseAapt2>True</AndroidUseAapt2>
        <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
        <EnableLLVM>False</EnableLLVM>
        <AndroidLinkResources>False</AndroidLinkResources>
        <AndroidEnableMultiDex>False</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
        <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
        <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
        <AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>False</AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>
        <AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>
    </PropertyGroup>-->

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
      <AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>False</AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>
      <JavaMaximumHeapSize>2G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
      <AndroidUseAapt2>True</AndroidUseAapt2>
      <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
      <AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-android'">
        <GoogleServicesJson Include="Platforms\Android\google-services.json" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />-->

        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="8.2.0" />

        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.93" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps" Version="8.0.93" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.93" />

        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.3.2" />

        <PackageReference Include="CoreCLR-NCalc" Version="3.1.253" />

        <PackageReference Include="FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable.HttpClient" Version="4.0.8" />

        <PackageReference Include="Microcharts" Version="0.9.5.9" />

        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision" Version="6.0.0-dev.20190919.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face" Version="2.8.0-preview.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />

        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Maui.Audio" Version="3.0.1" />

        <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="112.1.0" />

        <PackageReference Include="Sentry.Maui" Version="4.13.0" />

        <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.9.172" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.1.10" />

        <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Pdf.NET" Version="26.2.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Maui.PdfViewer" Version="26.2.13" />

        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="6.0.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Federation" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="6.0.*" />

        <PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.Maui" Version="7.1.0" />

        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData" Version="2.8.3.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core" Version="2.8.3.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.Ktx" Version="2.8.3.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Process" Version="2.8.3.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.MLKit.FaceDetection" Version="116.1.6.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.MLKit.Vision.Common" Version="117.3.0.10" />      
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" Version="124.0.0" />     
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Build.Download" Version="0.11.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Vision" Version="120.1.3.17" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity" Version="1.9.0.4" Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.Ktx" Version="1.9.0.4" Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'" />

        <PackageReference Include="BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui" Version="8.0.40.1" />            
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.png" Color="#1F669C" Resize="true" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#1F669C" BaseSize="256,256" Resize="true" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\**" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\**" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!--<Compile Remove="Platforms\Android\Controls\CameraSourcePreview.cs" />-->
        <Compile Remove="Controls\Facial\ImageCaptureSurfaceViewRenderer.cs" />
        <Compile Remove="Platforms\Android\Controls\MauiSignaturePadView.cs" />
        <Compile Remove="Platforms\Android\Renderers\SignatureViewRenderer.cs" />
        <Compile Remove="Services\Events\OnResumeEvent.cs" />
        <Compile Remove="Services\Web\SalsaClient.cs" />
        <Compile Remove="Views\Controls\LoadingDialog.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <AndroidResource Include="Platforms\Android\Resources\values\strings.xml" />
        <EmbeddedResource Include="MangoModel\SkillwebTasking.xsd" />
        <AdditionalFiles Include=".sonarlint\skillweb.maui_skillweb.maui_ayfrzqfphtlehxqfuhvz\CSharp\SonarLint.xml" />
        <Folder Include=".sonarlint\skillweb.maui_skillweb.maui_ayfmhccthtlehxqfuhtf\CSharp\" />
        <Folder Include="Platforms\Android\Renderers\" />
        <Folder Include="Services\Events\" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\Modals\LogonModal.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="README.md">
            <Pack>True</Pack>
            <PackagePath>\</PackagePath>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I have tested multiple configurations for the project file to stop VS from doing some crazy stuff internally and just deploy what is required with no luck.
Can someone tell me if I am missing something (note: PropertyGroups commented out are various attempts at trying to get this to work) or is there something I can do to get everything working.

Did you test in release mode or test on the apk file published by the VS command? In addition, did you try to uncheck AOT Compilation in release mode?
